# Vector space of all functions $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(n)$ exists.

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be the set of all functions $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(n)$ exists. Also, let $T:V \rightarrow V$ be defined by $(Tf)(n)=f(n+1)$ for any $n \in N$.

How do we find the eigenvalues for $T$? I am thinking that the functions $f\in V$ can be represented as a sum of all the basis function that satisfies $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(n)$. But I'm having a rough time imagining how could we get those basis. Also, given those eigenvalues how can we find the eigenvectors $f_n$?

Comment: Hint: If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue then $T(f(n))=\lambda \, f(n)$. This means $f$ should be such that $f(n+1)=\lambda \, f(n)$. For example, with $\lambda=1$, one can say a constant function is an eigenfunction. See if you can proceed from here.

Comment: I got stuck on thinking what other $\lambda$ are there. With respect to the other comment, I get that $f(n) = \lambda^n$ is an eigenfunction. but does this mean that there are an infinite number of eigenvalues for $T(f(n))$ on $(-1,1]$. Are there values of $\lambda$ such that $\lambda > 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find $\lambda$ so that there is some $f :\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the property that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(n)$ exists, and that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$(Tf)(n) = \lambda f(n).$$
Apply the definition of $T$ to get that if $f$ is an eigenvector of $T$, then
$$f(n+1) = \lambda f(n).$$
Now, if we apply this fact $k$ times when $n = 0$, you see that
$$f(k) = \lambda^k f(0).$$
If you want $f$ to be nonzero, but bounded as $n$ goes to $\infty$, you need $|\lambda| \le 1$, in which case, you see that the function
$$f(n) = \lambda^n$$
is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: I got confused after $f(n+1) = \lambda f(n)$. Does taking $k$ times mean that we take $(Tf)(n)=\lambda f(n)$ $k$ times? So we could say that $f(k+n) = \lambda^k f(n)$. Also how does one take into consideration functions like $f(n)=\frac{c}{n}$ or any function at all that cannot be written as $f(n) = \lambda^n$. Does this also mean that we have an infinite number of eigenvalues?